# SQL Server 2008 Connection String to Database "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server 2008 on my remote server within `web.config`.

On localhost the roles and all are working fine.

When I tried to configure it on a production server, I get the error:

> Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

in my `web.config`.

I am generating the entities from an `.edmx` file.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="IntranetSQLEntities"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/NTUserModel.csdl|res://*/NTUserModel.ssdl|res://*/NTUserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=';Data Source=xyz;Integrated Security=False;User Id=xyz;Password=xyz;MultipleActiveResultSets=True';" />
```

Later in the `web.config`, I add the following:

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="IntranetSQLEntities"
            applicationName="/"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,  
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz" />
        </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
        connectionStringName="IntranetSQLEntities"
        applicationName="/"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xyz"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

In my `machine.config`, there is still that `aspnetdb.mdf` file.

Could that be the problem?

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +5384504
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +66
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString, SqlCredential credential) +26
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +6
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +49

[ArgumentException: An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: connectionString]
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +131
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +149
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +762
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9866480
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in e:\inetpub\Intra.Net\wwwroot\nt-portal\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:512
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +235
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: check out [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) to check the syntax of your EF connection string.

Comment: When i say: "Integrated Security=SSPI;" then i get the error:  
"Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'." Why isn't it accepting the user and password i'm passing to the connection string ?

Edit: Ok i forgot to include The database name. Now i only get the error:"Keyword not supported: 'metadata'"

Comment: (So the syntax is now fine, i checked it with your link. The metadata / aspnetdb.mdf is still the problem..?)

Comment: So you are getting the metadata error?

Comment: yes thats the error i'm getting. I edited my question and added the full stack trace.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: yes im Using the Entity Framework. At least i did it on localhost.
There, i had the following connection string: 
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IntranetSQLEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NTUserModel.csdl|res://*/NTUserModel.ssdl|res://*/NTUserModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=intranetSQL;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Solved it with:
http://www.studiocoast.com.au/knowledgebase/6/aspnet/using-sql-server-instead-of-aspnetdbmdf.aspx